# how to pass my image to facebook feed dialog android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using following code to post on a user's wall.

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
    params.putString("message", facebookMessage);
    params.putString("link", ComLabelConstants.FACEBOOK_LINK);
    params.putString("name", linkname); 
    params.putString("picture", "http://some link"); 
    params.putString("caption", ComLabelConstants.FACEBOOK_LINK_CAPTION);
    params.putString("description", "This is description"); 
     // displaying facebook dialogs
    mFacebook.dialog(FbookAlertBoxActivity.this, "feed", params,new SampleDialogListener(this, mAsyncRunner));
```

Now, I want to use my own image in drawable folder to post on user's wall and not from any link. Can we do that? anyone have solution for this.

Comment: can you write code for SampleDialogListener as well. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't publish an image directly to a feed like you are asking - you can only pass a link to the image.

The only solution is to upload the image to a web server and then pass the URL of the image as the picture parameter.

Comment: ya mate, I think i have to do something like that. We can't pass an image to the feed URL. Thanks for the response.

Comment: stuck in the same problem, let me know if you have found an alternate method